# PDFBox Freezes at Print() Command

Tags: java, pdf, printing, pdfbox

I'm trying to use PDFBox to print an existing PDF file. Here's the code:

```
public void sendToPrinter(){
    File PDFFile = new File("Example.pdf");

    try {
        PDDocument pd = PDDocument.load(PDFFile);
        pd.print();
        pd.close();
    } catch (IOException | PrinterException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: Couldn't find pdf or printers");
    }
}
```

When I run it, however, the program freezes at `pd.print()`. No exceptions are thrown, no print dialog appears. It just doesn't do anything. Has anyone had this problem before?

Specs: Mac OS X Yosemite, PDFBox v1.8.9, JDK1.8.0_05, HP Photosmart printer

Comment: What version are you using? Are you able to display the file with the PDFReader command line utility? Are you able to print it with the PrintPDF command line utility? Does it happen with every PDF or just with one specific one? Can you share the PDF file?

Comment: I'm using the latest version—1.8.9. I haven't used either command line utility but all three PDF files I've tested have opened in a normal PDF Viewer, but not in PDFBox.

Comment: Here's one of the PDFs I tried. It's just 1 page with barely anything on it: http://cl.ly/c0cX/download/nYPhhd.pdf

Comment: I tested with 1.8.9. It opens in PDFReader, it prints there, and it also prints with your code. So the cause is something related to your configuration. Please add that into your question (OS version, JDK, printer), and ask the same on the PDFBox user mailing list: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/

Comment: Thanks for checking all that. For future testing, what should happen when the `print()` function completes. Does a dialog show up or does it just start printing directly?

Comment: I get a print dialog. To print without dialog, use silentPrint(). If possible, please update your JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem. My `print()` command worked when I put all the PDF work onto another thread. For reference:

```
public void sendToPrinter() {

        //Create new Task
        Task task = new Task<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() {

                //Reference the PDF file
                File PDFFile = new File("File.pdf");

                try {
                    //Load PDF & create a Printer Job
                    PDDocument pd = PDDocument.load(PDFFile);
                    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                    job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(pd));

                    //Show native print dialog & wait for user to hit "print"
                    if (job.printDialog()) {
                        job.print();
                    }

                    pd.close();
                } catch (IOException | PrinterException ex) {
                }

                return true;
            }
        };
        //Run task on new thread
        new Thread(task).start();

}
```